# PacMan Game : how to let the monesters follow the player?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT7F3.png)Actually i am a beginer in java , i tried to create one monester and let it find the shortest path to the player but unforutnatly the monesters moves in horible way(each step the player takes , the monester moves after him , suddenly the monester jumps) , so main problem here is :

1. the monesters jump in fornt of the player in each corner
2. the monester moving step by step (when i release the button it stops ) i need it to keep following the player.

i have created these classes related with the question : 
-Game class ( initials grid,wall,monester,food)

-Square class the component of each grid

-ghost class needs a square in the constrictor called current then it will change this current to the next nieghbour nearest to the chasedSquare.

```
 ghost.add(new Ghost(grid.get(2).get(2)));      // just for expermental purposes
```

```
public ArrayList<Square> findNieghbours(){
     ArrayList<Square> nieghbours=new ArrayList();
     int currentX=current.getX();
     int currentY=current.getY();

     if(currentX<29&&!grid.get(currentY/30).get(currentX/30+1).isWall()){
       nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30+1).get(currentY/30));
     }
     if(currentX>0&&!grid.get(currentY/30).get(currentX/30-1).isWall()){
        nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30-1).get(currentY/30));
     }
     if(currentY<29&&!grid.get(currentY/30+1).get(currentX/30+1).isWall()){
        nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30).get(currentY/30+1));
     }
     if(currentY>0&&!grid.get(currentY/30-1).get(currentX/30).isWall()){
       nieghbours.add(grid.get(currentX/30).get(currentY/30-1));
     }

     return nieghbours;
 }
```

```
public void Chase(Square chasedSquare){
    ArrayList<Square> nieghbours=findNieghbours();

    Square lowest=nieghbours.get(0);   // try catch??

     for(Square square : nieghbours){
       if(Math.sqrt((square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX())^2+(square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX())^2)<Math.sqrt((lowest.getX()-chasedSquare.getX())^2+(lowest.getX()-chasedSquare.getX())^2)){
           lowest=square;
       }

     }
     current=lowest;
 }
```

then i call the method chase for the ghost giving it the currentBlock of the player.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your `Chase` method. The ^ operator is not a power operator. You should either use the Math.pow method, or multiply the value itself instead:

`Math.pow(square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX(), 2)`

or

`(square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX()) * (square.getX()-chasedSquare.getX())`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `Chase` function. `^` is the bitwise exclusive OR operator in Java (see [Java Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). You can use the `Math.pow()` method to get the square of a value:

```
double x = 2.0
double xSq = Math.pow(x, 2)
```

Check [Math.pow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) for more details.